# How to install win98 into virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have a win98 folder. I created an win98.iso from that folder.

I created new virtual machine called win98.

In settings > Storage > Controller FLoppy : its not accepting the iso image.

I dont know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried cranking a CD into a floppy disk drive? I hope not.

Add a CD/DVD drive if you don't have one already and then use the ISO with that one as a source.

Comment: Luckily 5¼" floppy drives have become extinct long ago...